# disable button if the input field is empty and enable if there is text

Tags: javascript

I am a new learner and I am facing a problem. I want to create a simple messaging app and I want that if there is no text inside the input field then the button should be disabled. Help me out.
Here is the code:

```js
let sendMessage = document.getElementById("sendMessage");
sendMessage.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let val = document.getElementById("val");
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  let pTxt = document.createTextNode(val.value);
  p.appendChild(pTxt);
  val.value = "";
  let messages = document.getElementById("messages");
  messages.appendChild(p);
  if (val.value === "") {
    sendMessage.disabled = true;
  } else {
    sendMessage.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="messages"></div>
<input type="text" id="val" />
<button id="sendMessage">Send</button>
```

Comment: Set the button as disabled on initial state, then while the user start to type call a function to enable or disable the button by onchange attr in input

Comment: `val.value = "";` should be the last operation, otherwise the `if (val.value === "") {` makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `input` event to set `disabled` to false or true. Set `disabled` to true by default and after `button` was clicked.

```js
let sendMessage = document.getElementById("sendMessage");
let input = document.getElementById("val");

sendMessage.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let val = document.getElementById("val");
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  let pTxt = document.createTextNode(val.value);
  p.appendChild(pTxt);
  val.value = "";
  let messages = document.getElementById("messages");
  messages.appendChild(p);
  sendMessage.disabled = true;
});

input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  if(input.value.length > 0){
     sendMessage.disabled = false;
  } else {
    sendMessage.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="messages"></div>
   <input type="text" id="val"/>
   <button id="sendMessage" disabled>Send</button>
   <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a disabled class for the button if you use custom button.
Then listen to the input change and toggle the class on button if the input have value.

With your code :

```js
const button = document.getElementById('sendMessage');
const input = document.getElementById('message-input');
const messagesBox = document.getElementById('messages');

input.addEventListener('input', () => sendMessage.disabled = input.value === '');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  let pTxt = document.createTextNode(input.value);
  p.appendChild(pTxt);
  messagesBox.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="messages"></div>
   <input type="text" id="message-input" />
   <button id="sendMessage" disabled >Send</button>
   <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i am new and you made it so complex for me to understand try to explain in easy worlds for new comers

Answer (score 1):

Set a <strike>`keyup`</strike> `input` handler for the input field and a `click` handler for the button. In the snippet [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is used.

```js
document.addEventListener(`input`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const isInput = evt.target.closest(`#val`);
  const isBttn = evt.target.closest(`#sendMessage`); 
  
  if (isInput) {
    document.querySelector(`#sendMessage`).disabled = !isInput.value.trim();
  }
  
  if (isBttn) {
    isBttn.disabled = isBttn;
    const inputField = document.querySelector(`#val`); 
    document.querySelector(`#messages`).insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, 
      `<li>${inputField.value.trim()}</li>`);
    inputField.value = ``;
    inputField.focus();
  } 
}
```

```html
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<input type="text" id="val" />
<button id="sendMessage" disabled>Send</button>
```

Comment: Don't use `"keyup"` since `"paste"` event will not trigger it. Use instead the `"input"` Event. It'll respond to any change-of-input which is desirable.